# Scroll text div on hover and return to first element

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to replace "home" button with another text when I hover by mouse on it instead of it repeating itself?

```
<ul class="topnav">
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
</ul>


jQuery(function($) {

    $('.topnav li').find('a[href]').parent().each(function(span, li){
        li = $(li); span = $('<span>' + li.find('a').html() + '<\/span>');
        li.hover(function(){
        span.stop().animate({marginTop: '-60'}, 250);
        }, function(){
        span.stop().animate({marginTop: '0'}, 250);
        }).prepend(span);
    });

});
```

Here is the example: http://jsfiddle.net/fxdigi/3YNHp/1/

Comment: its working in fiddle, what except you want??

Comment: how about this : http://jsfiddle.net/3YNHp/7/

Comment: @diEcho Thanks mate. I know that way, but wanted to make switch with text when hovering so that two different texts float.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check my variant http://jsfiddle.net/3YNHp/5/

It uses markup:

```
<ul class="topnav">
    <li>
        <a href="#" data-hover-text="Mohe">Home</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And changed javascript:

```
$('.topnav li').find('a[href]').parent().each(function() {
    var li   = $(this),
        a    = li.find('a'),
        span = $('<span>' + a.data('hover-text') + '<\/span>');

    li.hover(function() {
        a.stop().animate({marginTop: '-64'}, 250);
    },
    function() {
        a.stop().animate({marginTop: '0'}, 250);
    })
    .append(span);
});
```

Comment: @ dfsq Brilliant my friend. That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks billion.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is put the text you want to show on hover in the anchor to start with like so

```
<ul class="topnav">
<li data-orig="Home"><a href="#">Go to</a></li>
</ul>
```

And then in a data attribute place the text you want to show originally.

Then modify the javascript slightly to pull out the new values.

```
jQuery(function($) {

    $('.topnav li').find('a[href]').parent().each(function(span, li){
        li = $(li); span = $('<span>'+ li.attr('data-orig') +'<\/span>');
        li.hover(function(){
        span.stop().animate({marginTop: '-60'}, 250);
        }, function(){
        span.stop().animate({marginTop: '0'}, 250);
        }).prepend(span);
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mate. That works,too. It is only I need to re-adjust the background of the 2nd object when hovering. cheers.

Comment: Hi mates, I just made a little modifications so that it can scroll the div instead of the span. I hope anyone find it useful. Thanks for the help 
here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/fxdigi/ZhUx8/