# Jquery easing effect

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-effects

I've been trying over the last few hours to implement a jQuery easing effect to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9052288/scroll-text-div-on-hover-and-return-to-first-element) (code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fxdigi/ZhUx8/)), but all in vain.

It didn't work at all. What I'm trying to do is make the example work the same way, but add `easeOutBack` to it so that if I hovered on the text, it would begin with the `easeOutBack` effect until the next text shows up. And again `easeOutBack` effect would happen when I unhover the text.

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: What actually doesn't work? In chrome there is sliding animation

Comment: not, the original one is ok, but wanted to know how to add some easing effects. Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

what about this -  http://jsfiddle.net/ZhUx8/1/.

```
jQuery(function($) {

    $('.topnav li').find('a[href]').parent().each(function() {
        var li   = $(this),
            a    = li.find('a'),
            div = $('<div>' + '<\/div>');

        li.hover(function() {
            a.stop().animate({marginTop: '-64'}, 500, "easeInOutBack");
        },
        function() {
            a.stop().animate({marginTop: '0'}, 500, "easeInOutBack");
        })
        .append(span);
    });

});
```

make sure to ad this to your head tag.

```
<script src="http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/jquery.easing.1.3.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
```

Comment: @ Andrew, you are amazing my friend. That's exactly what I wanted. I was just a little confused where to place the easing effect, but you got it right. Thanks a lot.

Comment: BTW mates, here is the code that works as I wanted. I had a little issue with easing out back for one side, but got fixed. here is the code [link](http://jsfiddle.net/fxdigi/t9TEx/) Thanks for all your efforts.